# How to bring georeferenced raster data into MAPublisher?

Tags: raster, illustrator, mapublisher

What is the appropriate method to import a georeferenced raster image into MAPublisher? I have been able to import other forms of map data, and created map views and such for them, but I am now interested in importing a raster image with spatial data and retain that data within MAPublisher. Do I need to have some sort of GIS data in the document before I can import the georeferenced raster image? Or is it possible to bring it in on it's own?

Comment: I was unable to create decent tags for this, so if anyone is willing to, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I believe I have figured out one way to bring the data in via creating a geotiff of the raster data in ArcMap, and then registering the placed image within Illustrator to the geotiff. I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way to go about doing this? I have tried importing a vector image and registering it to the same set of spatial data, but it is definitely not working. Any help on these questions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading a geotiff is on page 24 of this pdf
http://download.avenza.com/Downloads/Docs/MAPublisher/MP95_QuickStartGuide.pdf

check vector data and geotiff are on the same datum and projection.

Comment: Thanks, Mapperz. I was able to load in my raster data, but I now have an additional problem. 

The vector data I am trying to reference has no GCS or projection. I want to reference it to the raster data. I have been able to size the vector data to match the raster data, but every time I try to register it to the raster data, it makes it incredibly large and goes off the canvas. Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: When you have matched raster to the vector then lock the layer. It should stop that issue.